# explanation on javascript function call passing this

Tags: javascript, javascript-objects

I am reading the "Javascript the Good Parts" book and trying out examples to understand the concepts. I came across one example and could not understand. Please look at the code below and let me understand where I am going wrong:

```
//Augmenting the Function prototype with method
Function.prototype.method = function(name, func){
  if (typeof this.prototype[name] !== "function"){
      this.prototype[name]=func;
    return this;
  }
}

// why do we have the (this) at the end of the return statement.
/*Number.method("integer", function(){
  return Math[this < 0 ? 'ceil': 'floor'](this);
});*/

//According to me the function should have been like below:
Number.method("integer", function(val){ // we get a function and we need to pass the value and the value will be evaluated and returned.
  return Math[val < 0 ? 'ceil': 'floor'];
});
//According to my understanding the calling function should be something like below.
alert((-10/3).integer(-10/3);
```

I know that my approach is not working but finding hard to get the reasoning. Please update me with some example to reinforce the concepts.

Sharing the link to the Fiddle - [Fiddle - link](https://jsfiddle.net/prashdeep/nunLej57/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Math[val < 0 ? 'ceil': 'floor']` is a function. Think about `Math.ceil` or `Math.floor`.

So the method you added to `Number` will return a function instead of a value.

While add `(this)` at the end of the line will call this function with the value of caller, in your case -10/3. So it will return the expected value to you.

Comment: In that case, does it imply that (-10/3) is an object and then I call the function `integer` on the object and when I call a function on the object, the `this` keyword will point to the object and hence, the `Math[ceil | floor]`gets the reference to the object i.e (-10/3). Is my understanding correct ? Please comment.

Comment: Yes, everything is right except that (-10/3) is actually a primitive, but when you try to call a method of it, javascript will wrap it as Number(-10/3), which is a true object.

Comment: One more learning for me. when we call say 2.toString(), we get an error where it is treated as primitive, whereas when we call (2).toString(), we get "2". Is my hypothesis that putting a number inside the parenthesis gets treated as an object whereas just calling 2.toString() is treated as primitive correct?

Comment: It is actually a javascript interpreter thing. The dot after 2 will be priorly interpreted as the demical dot (say, `2.17`). And note that `2.` is actually valid in javascript and you can do things like `var a = 2.;` So it is not because it is treated as primitive, it is because interpreter didn't understand that you are going to call a method on `2`. A tricky way to do it is `2..toString()`, where the first dot is interpreted as decimal dot and the second one is as method call dot. (sorry didn't find a better name for these two.)

Answer (score 1):

> According to my understanding the calling function should be something like `(-10/3).integer(-10/3)`

That's where your misconception is. Why should you need to repeat the number? No, the *method* is supposed to be called as

```
(-10/3).integer() // -3
```

without any arguments - the value it acts on is the `Number` instance (`this` in the method).

If you were going to pass the number as the argument, there would be no need to make it a method, rather it should be a static function:

```
Number.integer = function(val) {
    return Math[val < 0 ? 'ceil': 'floor'](val);
//                                         ^^^ still passing it here, of course
};
Number.integer(-10/3) // -3
```

Such is viable as well, especially when the argument is not guaranteed to be a number, as can be seen by various static `Number` and `Math` functions.